# Some way to check whether if a user unuscribed from an event

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, parse-server

I'm making a chat app which should present the user some information. One of these things, is the amount of users that are connected to a particular chat at a moment.

I'm using Parse Server Livequeries for this. My "chat" object is a Parse class which has all the info regarding a particular chat, including it's messages and user amount (which is an int). This is the code:

```
   getLocationName().then(  area => {            // I get the area
        assignOrCreateChat(area).then( r => {
            let chat:any = r; // fix

            // Open a subscription to the chat
            let query = new Parse.Query("Chat");
            query.equalTo("objectId", chat.id);
            let subscription = query.subscribe();

            // Set the event handlers
            subscription.on('open', () => {
                let num = chat.get("userCount");
                if(isNaN(num)){
                    num = 1;
                }else{
                    num += 1;
                }
                chat.set("userCount", num);
                chat.save();
            });

            subscription.on('close', () => {
                chat.set("users", chat.get("users")-1);
                chat.save();
            })

           // subscription.emit("open");


       }).catch(e => console.log(e))
   }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

As you probably have guessed, it all works perfectly, except for the close event. Obviously, I could do a simple:

```
subscription.emit("close");
```

... on some app event fired when closing the window (as ionViewDidLeave in this particular Ionic application), **but it won't work if the app just crashes, gets disconnected from the server, or any other not-that-rare circumstances.** These situations would lead into this number getting bigger and bigger without really representing the real users.

So, what approach can I take, in order to have a real estimate of the users who are connected to a particular chat?

Thank you!

Comment: `rxjs` tag seems to be misleading as neither the question nor the code sample are related to rx.